# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function http_response()

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de correr este simple ejemplo:

```html
<?php
$is_ok = http_response($url); // returns true only if http response code < 400
```

Pero me genera el siguiente error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function http_response()`

Verifiqué que estuviese activa la extensión curl en el directorio php de xampp donde esta configurada mi variable de entorno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al parecer todo está bien sin embargo me arroja ese error cuando intento ejecutar la función.

Estoy utilizano como sistema operativo Windows. Que debo hacer para que me reconozca la función, supongo que debo instalar una libreria, pero no consigo tutoriales de como instalarla.

**Versión de php instalada:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 1. Revisa la documentación del ejemplo para que sepas como está declarado el método http_response() que no es nativo de php. 2. No uses notepad para editar archivos de código (les pone BOM) y te va a dar sorpresas desagradables cuando muevas tu código a un servicio de hosting (no windows); Instala NotePad++ (NotePad plus plus) Para edición y revisión rápida de archivos planos de código

Answer (score 0):

Quizás porque la función que mencionas no existe de forma nativa ni en sus librerías principales:
https://www.php.net/results.php?q=http_response&l=es&p=all

Si quieres obtener la respuesta que devuelve una URL puedes usar la función `get_headers`:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.google.com';
    $headers = get_headers($url, 1);

    print_r($headers);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-headers.php